# XIB gave a constraint to launch the WKWebView, but there is an error A multiplier of 0 or a nil..... How can I fix this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, constraints, wkwebview

an error occurred while trying to run webview on xib using PageViewController.

Thread 1: "NSLayoutConstraint for <WKWebView: 0x14d0a8e00; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x28109b600>>: A multiplier of 0 or a nil second item together with a location for the first attribute creates an illegal constraint of a location equal to a constant. Location attributes must be specified in pairs."

I made a view in xib (Not a ..cell. This is a view.) and made a wkwebview with code using that view, but I am having a hard time because of these errors. Is there a solution?
Below is the code I wrote.

```
CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
//CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.safeAreaContainerView.layer.frame.size.width, self.safeAreaContainerView.layer.frame.size.height);  //I only received width and height as 0 and annotated it.
self.wkwebview = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
self.wkwebview.UIDelegate = self;
self.wkwebview.navigationDelegate = self;
self.wkwebview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[self.wkwebview sizeToFit];
self.wkwebview.scrollView.scrollEnabled= YES;
[self.safeAreaContainerView addSubview:self.wkwebview];
[self.safeAreaContainerView sendSubviewToBack:self.wkwebview];

//WKWebView Layout Setting
NSLayoutConstraint *firstViewConstraintTop = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.wkwebview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.safeAreaContainerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:0];

NSLayoutConstraint *firstViewConstraintBottom = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.safeAreaContainerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.wkwebview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:0];

NSLayoutConstraint *firstViewConstraintLeadingSpace = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.wkwebview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.safeAreaContainerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1 constant:0];

NSLayoutConstraint *firstViewConstraintTrailingSpace = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.safeAreaContainerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.wkwebview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1 constant:0];

[self.safeAreaContainerView addConstraints:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: firstViewConstraintTop, firstViewConstraintBottom, firstViewConstraintLeadingSpace, firstViewConstraintTrailingSpace, nil]];
```

Does it not work in View when coding the WKWebView to the XIB?
Is it only available on TableViewCell or CollectionViewCell?

Comment: Try adding ```self.wkwebview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;``` as part of your configuration. If you set up the constraints correctly (I did not check in detail) you can create that with ```CGRectZero``` and it should work.

Comment: I tried this method, but it still won't run. In addition, autoresize=W+H was added to the error content.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar and use the code I posted here to embed the webview into its container view.

[How to: Constrain subview to safeArea Obj-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62390762/how-to-constrain-subview-to-safearea-obj-c/62391897#62391897)

Apart from using that I do preciously little on the webview itself, basically the following

```
webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:GCRectZero];
webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

and nothing else.

HIH

Comment: I'm Sorry.

Do you mean creating a View in the containerView?

tried to create ContainerView on the XIB, but it did not exist.



+ ( void ) embed:( UIView * ) child
        into:( UIView * ) parent 

child = View, parent= ContainalView ?

Is the above correct?

Comment: The child = webview, the parent = web container view. In your case it looks like child = self.wkwebview and parent = self.safeAreaContainerView.

Comment: Thanks to you, I solved it. 
I don't know if the method I implemented is the right answer. 
After running the Xib through caculating the size of RootView with CGRect, there has been no error.!

Comment: @Hee Nice I am glad and thank you for letting me know - I appreciate it.